# Is there any other way to avoid duplicate data while scraping and avoid storing the same data in database?

Tags: django, django-models, beautifulsoup, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a simple model.
models.py

```
class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

then I'm scraping the data from some sources and want to store in this table.

```
toi_r = requests.get("some source")
toi_soup = BeautifulSoup(toi_r.content, 'html5lib')
toi_headings = toi_soup.findAll("h2", {"class": "entry-title format-icon"})[0:9]
toi_category = toi_soup.findAll("a", {"class": ""})[0:9]
toi_news = [th.text for th in toi_headings]
toi_cat = [tr.text for tr in toi_category]

for th in toi_headings:
    toi_news.append(th.text)

for tr in toi_category:
    toi_cat.append(tr.text)

for title, category in zip(toi_news, toi_cat):
    n = Content.objects.create(title=title, category=category)
```

So here, error is UNIQUE Constraint failed. So, If I remove the UNIQUE Constraint, then everything works but mulitple copies of data are stored as the page refreshes. Is there any other way to work with this?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the unique constraint? You can simply catch it in a `try`/`except` block.

Comment: If unique constraint is present, then it doesn't work django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:

Comment: The solution depends on the behaviour that you want. Do you want duplicates to overwrite existing records or do you want duplicates to be ignored/skipped?

Comment: I want duplicates to be ignored.

Comment: Then I don't see your issue with the suggestion by @Selcuk. Catch the `IntegrityError` and continue the loop